# use spark to read avro data and got org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.lang.String Exception

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, avro

I am using following code to read avro in spark:

```
val inputData = sc.hadoopFile(inputPath,
  classOf[AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
  classOf[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord]]).map(t => 
{ val genericRecord = t._1.datum()  
(String)genericRecord.get("name") });
```

the loading part works fine but the converting to String part failed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

To simplify the example, I use a line

```
(String)genericRecord.get("name")
```

Actually that part is from a library, which is used fine in a hadoop map reduce job. However, when I am using that library in spark now, it failed because of the above exception.

I know I can change the code to `genericRecord.get("name").toString()` to make it work, but because I am using it fine in another hadoop mapreduce job, I am hoping all the utf8 could be automatically converted to String so that I don't need to change all the code logic.

To sum up, How to make all the `org.apache.avro.util.Utf8` in `GenericRecord` automatically converted into `java.lang.String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the solution is to use `AvroKey` instead of `AvroWrapper`. below code works, all the`org.apache.avro.util.Utf8` will automatically convert to `java.lang.String`. No exception any more.

```
val inputData = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(inputPath,
classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
classOf[AvroKey[GenericRecord]],
classOf[NullWritable]).map(t => 
{ val genericRecord = t._1.datum()  
(String)genericRecord.get("name") });
```